# Spring boot REST Services allow access only through F5 Load balancer

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, load-balancing

I have a Spring boot REST service running on 2 Apache Tomcat servers (2 INSTANCES). Also, I have an F5 load balancer configured to forward requests between 2 tomcat server instances.

**Actual:**

```
https://f5-host/api/example --> working HTTP: 200
https://tomcat-host1/api/example --> working HTTP: 200
https://tomcat-host2/api/example --> working HTTP: 200
```

The problem is I am suggested to do code changes to restrict access when service is accessed directly via tomcat servers. I am thinking this can be achieved directly through configuration in Apache tomcat servers. Could someone suggest the best approach/config details here, please?

**Expected:**

```
https://f5-host/api/example --> working HTTP: 200
https://tomcat-host1/api/example --> Access Denied HTTP: 403
https://tomcat-host2/api/example --> Access Denied HTTP: 403
```

Comment: Which Spring Boot version?

Comment: Spring boot 2.1.8 Release